# Css box shadow moving to the top and left

Tags: html, css

[image]

CSS & Html:

```css
body {background:#ccc}

.box h3{
  text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    top:80px;
}
.box {
    width:70%;
    height:200px;
    background:#FFF;
    margin:40px auto;
}

.effect3
{
  position: relative;
}
.effect3:before
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box effect3">
<h3>Effect 3</h3>
</div>
```

I am trying to decorate a box with a shadow.

The above css is for the shadow bottom and left (in the red circle).
What can be the css to apply to the top and left (red arrow)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use these code for top left box-shadow:

```
.effect3:before {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 3px;
    width: 18%;
    top: 24px;
    max-width: 300px;
    background: #777;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -8px 15px 10px #777;
    -moz-box-shadow: -8px 15px 10px #777;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(87deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(87deg);
    transform: rotate(87deg);
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
  background: #ccc
}

.box h3 {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;
}

.box {
  width: 70%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

.effect3 {
  position: relative;
}

.effect3:before {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    left: -46px;
    width: 20%;
    bottom: 15px;
    top: 25%;
    max-width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #777;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
    box-shadow: -10px -5px 10px #777;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-93deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-93deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-93deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-93deg);
    transform: rotate(-93deg);
}
```

I think this is what you asking...

Comment: The result wasn't close enough but I am changing the values and now is perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
-webkit-box-shadow: -6px -8px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:    -6px -8px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow:         -6px -8px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
```

Generated using http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/

Comment: Sorry it's not that result I want.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `after` and changing the `before` like so:

```
.effect3:before {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    left: 15px;
    width: 50%;
    bottom: 15px;
    top: 4%;
    max-width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #777;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
    box-shadow: -10px -5px 10px #777;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform: rotate(3deg);
}

.effect3:after {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    top: 80%;
    max-width: 300px;
    background: #777;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o30LLydr/)

Comment: I am sorry. I meant to the left-up (not at top) and only one shadow.